# dotnet tool restore fails with Unable to load the service index for source - 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

I have a private nuget feed hosted through our Azure DevOps Server 2020 (Azure Artifacts), which I try to access from a build pipeline. Here's the command using a `.Net Core` task (v2):

`C:\Agent\_work\_tool\dotnet\dotnet.exe tool restore --verbosity detailed`

Unfortunately, I always get the following error:

```
C:\Agent\_work\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.403\NuGet.targets(131,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json. [C:\Users\DevOps-AzAgent$\AppData\Local\Temp\c1xjkwos.iwp\restore.csproj]
C:\Agent\_work\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.403\NuGet.targets(131,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [C:\Users\DevOps-AzAgent$\AppData\Local\Temp\c1xjkwos.iwp\restore.csproj]
```

My Azure DevOps Agents are running using a MSA, which has no permissions on our Azure DevOps Server nor the nuget feed. The agent should authenticate by using the `security token` (`System.AccessToken`) provided by the build engine. Our `Build Service` has `Contributor` permissions to the feed.

To get the authentication right, I inserted a `NuGet authenticate` task. Here's the output of the task:

```
Installing the Azure Artifacts Credential Provider (.NET Framework) to 'C:\Users\DevOps-AzAgent$\.nuget\plugins\netfx\CredentialProvider.Microsoft'. This credential provider is compatible with nuget.exe 4.8.0.5385 or later, and MSBuild 15.8.166.59604 or later.

Installing the Azure Artifacts Credential Provider (.NET Core) to 'C:\Users\DevOps-AzAgent$\.nuget\plugins\netcore\CredentialProvider.Microsoft'. This credential provider is compatible with dotnet SDK 2.1 or later.

Setting up the credential provider to use the identity 'XXX Build Service (XXX)' for feeds in your organization/collection starting with:
  http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/
```

I checked the environment variables after executing the `NuGet authenticate` task and it creates the following ones:

- VSS_NUGET_ACCESSTOKEN
- VSS_NUGET_URI_PREFIXES

Here are the logs of the `dotnet tool restore` command:

```
         Using C:\Users\DevOps-AzAgent$\.nuget\plugins\netcore\CredentialProvider.Microsoft\CredentialProvider.Microsoft.dll as a credential provider plugin.
             [CredentialProvider.113308]Running in plug-in mode
             [CredentialProvider.113308]Command-line v0.1.28+103227dd070f2b048ce0ae9bc259f12d509d85e2: C:\Users\DevOps-AzAgent$\.nuget\plugins\netcore\CredentialProvider.Microsoft\CredentialProvider.Microsoft.dll -Plugin
             [CredentialProvider.113308]Handling 'Request' 'Initialize'. Time elapsed in ms: 4 - Payload: {"ClientVersion":"5.11.1","Culture":"de-DE","RequestTimeout":"00:00:05"}
             [CredentialProvider.113308]Sending response: 'Request' 'Initialize'. Time elapsed in ms: 5
             [CredentialProvider.113308]Time elapsed in milliseconds after sending response 'Request' 'Initialize': 7
             [CredentialProvider.113308]Handling 'Request' 'GetOperationClaims'. Time elapsed in ms: 0 - Payload: {}
             [CredentialProvider.113308]Sending response: 'Request' 'GetOperationClaims'. Time elapsed in ms: 6
             [CredentialProvider.113308]Time elapsed in milliseconds after sending response 'Request' 'GetOperationClaims': 15
             [CredentialProvider.113308]Handling 'Request' 'SetLogLevel'. Time elapsed in ms: 1 - Payload: {"LogLevel":"Debug"}
             [CredentialProvider]Sending response: 'Request' 'SetLogLevel'. Time elapsed in ms: 2
             [CredentialProvider]Time elapsed in milliseconds after sending response 'Request' 'SetLogLevel': 12
             [CredentialProvider]Handling 'Request' 'GetAuthenticationCredentials'. Time elapsed in ms: 5 - Payload: {"Uri":"http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json","IsRetry":false,"IsNonInteractive":true,"CanShowDialog":false}
             [CredentialProvider]Creating a progress reporter with interval: 00:00:02
             [CredentialProvider]Handling auth request, Uri: http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json, IsRetry: False, IsNonInteractive: True, CanShowDialog: False
             [CredentialProvider]URI: http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json
             [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskServiceEndpointCredentialProvider - This credential provider must be run under the Team Build tasks for NuGet with external endpoint credentials. Appropriate environment variable needs to be set.
             [CredentialProvider]Skipping NuGetCredentialProvider.CredentialProviders.VstsBuildTaskServiceEndpoint.VstsBuildTaskServiceEndpointCredentialProvider, cannot provide credentials for http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json
             [CredentialProvider]Using NuGetCredentialProvider.CredentialProviders.VstsBuildTask.VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider to try to get credentials for http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json.
             [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - IsRetry: False
             [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - URI Prefixes:
             [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/
             [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - Matched prefix: http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/
             [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - Found credentials for endpoint http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json
             [CredentialProvider]Sending response: 'Request' 'GetAuthenticationCredentials'. Time elapsed in ms: 19
             [CredentialProvider]Time elapsed in milliseconds after sending response 'Request' 'GetAuthenticationCredentials': 23
             [CredentialProvider]Handling 'Request' 'GetAuthenticationCredentials'. Time elapsed in ms: 0 - Payload: {"Uri":"http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json","IsRetry":true,"IsNonInteractive":true,"CanShowDialog":false}
             [CredentialProvider]Creating a progress reporter with interval: 00:00:02
             [CredentialProvider]Handling auth request, Uri: http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json, IsRetry: True, IsNonInteractive: True, CanShowDialog: False
             [CredentialProvider]URI: http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json
             [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskServiceEndpointCredentialProvider - This credential provider must be run under the Team Build tasks for NuGet with external endpoint credentials. Appropriate environment variable needs to be set.
             [CredentialProvider]Skipping NuGetCredentialProvider.CredentialProviders.VstsBuildTaskServiceEndpoint.VstsBuildTaskServiceEndpointCredentialProvider, cannot provide credentials for http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json
             [CredentialProvider]Using NuGetCredentialProvider.CredentialProviders.VstsBuildTask.VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider to try to get credentials for http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json.
             [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - IsRetry: True
             [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - URI Prefixes:
             [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/
             [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - Matched prefix: http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/
             [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - Found credentials for endpoint http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json
             [CredentialProvider]Sending response: 'Request' 'GetAuthenticationCredentials'. Time elapsed in ms: 1
             [CredentialProvider]Time elapsed in milliseconds after sending response 'Request' 'GetAuthenticationCredentials': 1
             [CredentialProvider]Handling 'Request' 'GetAuthenticationCredentials'. Time elapsed in ms: 0 - Payload: {"Uri":"http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json","IsRetry":true,"IsNonInteractive":true,"CanShowDialog":false}
             [CredentialProvider]Creating a progress reporter with interval: 00:00:02
             [CredentialProvider]Handling auth request, Uri: http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json, IsRetry: True, IsNonInteractive: True, CanShowDialog: False
             [CredentialProvider]URI: http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json
             [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskServiceEndpointCredentialProvider - This credential provider must be run under the Team Build tasks for NuGet with external endpoint credentials. Appropriate environment variable needs to be set.
             [CredentialProvider]Skipping NuGetCredentialProvider.CredentialProviders.VstsBuildTaskServiceEndpoint.VstsBuildTaskServiceEndpointCredentialProvider, cannot provide credentials for http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json
             [CredentialProvider]Using NuGetCredentialProvider.CredentialProviders.VstsBuildTask.VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider to try to get credentials for http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json.
             [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - IsRetry: True
             [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - URI Prefixes:
             [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/
             [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - Matched prefix: http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/
             [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - Found credentials for endpoint http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json
             [CredentialProvider]Sending response: 'Request' 'GetAuthenticationCredentials'. Time elapsed in ms: 0
             [CredentialProvider]Time elapsed in milliseconds after sending response 'Request' 'GetAuthenticationCredentials': 0
             [CredentialProvider]Handling 'Request' 'GetAuthenticationCredentials'. Time elapsed in ms: 0 - Payload: {"Uri":"http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json","IsRetry":true,"IsNonInteractive":true,"CanShowDialog":false}
             [CredentialProvider]Creating a progress reporter with interval: 00:00:02
             [CredentialProvider]Handling auth request, Uri: http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json, IsRetry: True, IsNonInteractive: True, CanShowDialog: False
             [CredentialProvider]URI: http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json
             [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskServiceEndpointCredentialProvider - This credential provider must be run under the Team Build tasks for NuGet with external endpoint credentials. Appropriate environment variable needs to be set.
             [CredentialProvider]Skipping NuGetCredentialProvider.CredentialProviders.VstsBuildTaskServiceEndpoint.VstsBuildTaskServiceEndpointCredentialProvider, cannot provide credentials for http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json
             [CredentialProvider]Using NuGetCredentialProvider.CredentialProviders.VstsBuildTask.VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider to try to get credentials for http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json.
             [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - IsRetry: True
             [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - URI Prefixes:
             [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/
             [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - Matched prefix: http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/
             [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - Found credentials for endpoint http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json
             [CredentialProvider]Sending response: 'Request' 'GetAuthenticationCredentials'. Time elapsed in ms: 1
             [CredentialProvider]Time elapsed in milliseconds after sending response 'Request' 'GetAuthenticationCredentials': 1
     1>C:\Agent\_work\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.403\NuGet.targets(131,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json. [C:\Users\DevOps-AzAgent$\AppData\Local\Temp\qn20vf2i.kp0\restore.csproj]
C:\Agent\_work\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.403\NuGet.targets(131,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [C:\Users\DevOps-AzAgent$\AppData\Local\Temp\qn20vf2i.kp0\restore.csproj]
         NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Unable to load the service index for source http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json.
          ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
            at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
            at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.<>c__DisplayClass15_0`1.<<GetAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
         --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
            at NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.ExecuteWithFileLockedAsync[T](String filePath, Func`2 action, CancellationToken token)
            at NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.ExecuteWithFileLockedAsync[T](String filePath, Func`2 action, CancellationToken token)
            at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.GetAsync[T](HttpSourceCachedRequest request, Func`2 processAsync, ILogger log, CancellationToken token)
            at NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.GetServiceIndexResourceV3(SourceRepository source, DateTime utcNow, ILogger log, CancellationToken token)
            --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
            at NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.GetServiceIndexResourceV3(SourceRepository source, DateTime utcNow, ILogger log, CancellationToken token)
            at NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.TryCreate(SourceRepository source, CancellationToken token)
            at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository.GetResourceAsync[T](CancellationToken token)
            at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository.GetResourceAsync[T]()
            at NuGet.Protocol.HttpFileSystemBasedFindPackageByIdResourceProvider.TryCreate(SourceRepository sourceRepository, CancellationToken token)
            at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository.GetResourceAsync[T](CancellationToken token)
            at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository.GetResourceAsync[T]()
            at NuGet.Commands.SourceRepositoryDependencyProvider.EnsureResource()
            at NuGet.Commands.SourceRepositoryDependencyProvider.FindLibraryCoreAsync(LibraryRange libraryRange, SourceCacheContext cacheContext, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            at NuGet.Commands.SourceRepositoryDependencyProvider.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<<FindLibraryAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
         --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
            at NuGet.Commands.SourceRepositoryDependencyProvider.FindLibraryAsync(LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGetFramework targetFramework, SourceCacheContext cacheContext, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            at NuGet.DependencyResolver.ResolverUtility.<>c__DisplayClass9_1.<<FindLibraryFromSourcesAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
         --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
            at NuGet.DependencyResolver.ResolverUtility.FindLibraryFromSourcesAsync(LibraryRange libraryRange, IEnumerable`1 providers, Func`2 action)
            at NuGet.DependencyResolver.ResolverUtility.FindLibraryByVersionAsync(LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGetFramework framework, IEnumerable`1 providers, SourceCacheContext cacheContext, ILogger logger, CancellationToken token)
            at NuGet.DependencyResolver.ResolverUtility.FindPackageLibraryMatchAsync(LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGetFramework framework, IEnumerable`1 remoteProviders, IEnumerable`1 localProviders, SourceCacheContext cacheContext, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            at NuGet.DependencyResolver.ResolverUtility.FindLibraryMatchAsync(LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGetFramework framework, String runtimeIdentifier, IEnumerable`1 remoteProviders, IEnumerable`1 localProviders, IEnumerable`1 projectProviders, IDictionary`2 lockFileLibraries, SourceCacheContext cacheContext, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            at NuGet.DependencyResolver.ResolverUtility.FindLibraryEntryAsync(LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGetFramework framework, String runtimeIdentifier, RemoteWalkContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            at NuGet.DependencyResolver.RemoteDependencyWalker.CreateGraphNode(LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGetFramework framework, String runtimeName, RuntimeGraph runtimeGraph, Func`2 predicate, GraphEdge`1 outerEdge, TransitiveCentralPackageVersions transitiveCentralPackageVersions)
            at NuGet.DependencyResolver.RemoteDependencyWalker.CreateGraphNode(LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGetFramework framework, String runtimeName, RuntimeGraph runtimeGraph, Func`2 predicate, GraphEdge`1 outerEdge, TransitiveCentralPackageVersions transitiveCentralPackageVersions)
            at NuGet.DependencyResolver.RemoteDependencyWalker.WalkAsync(LibraryRange library, NuGetFramework framework, String runtimeIdentifier, RuntimeGraph runtimeGraph, Boolean recursive)
            at NuGet.Commands.ProjectRestoreCommand.WalkDependenciesAsync(LibraryRange projectRange, NuGetFramework framework, String runtimeIdentifier, RuntimeGraph runtimeGraph, RemoteDependencyWalker walker, RemoteWalkContext context, CancellationToken token)
            at NuGet.Commands.ProjectRestoreCommand.TryRestoreAsync(LibraryRange projectRange, IEnumerable`1 frameworkRuntimePairs, NuGetv3LocalRepository userPackageFolder, IReadOnlyList`1 fallbackPackageFolders, RemoteDependencyWalker remoteWalker, RemoteWalkContext context, Boolean forceRuntimeGraphCreation, CancellationToken token, TelemetryActivity telemetryActivity, String telemetryPrefix)
            at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.ExecuteRestoreAsync(NuGetv3LocalRepository userPackageFolder, IReadOnlyList`1 fallbackPackageFolders, RemoteWalkContext context, CancellationToken token, TelemetryActivity telemetryActivity)
            at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken token)
            at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.ExecuteAsync(RestoreSummaryRequest summaryRequest, CancellationToken token)
            at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.ExecuteAndCommitAsync(RestoreSummaryRequest summaryRequest, CancellationToken token)
            at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.CompleteTaskAsync(List`1 restoreTasks)
            at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.RunAsync(IEnumerable`1 restoreRequests, RestoreArgs restoreContext, CancellationToken token)
            at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.RunAsync(RestoreArgs restoreContext, CancellationToken token)
            at NuGet.Build.Tasks.BuildTasksUtility.RestoreAsync(DependencyGraphSpec dependencyGraphSpec, Boolean interactive, Boolean recursive, Boolean noCache, Boolean ignoreFailedSources, Boolean disableParallel, Boolean force, Boolean forceEvaluate, Boolean hideWarningsAndErrors, Boolean restorePC, Boolean cleanupAssetsForUnsupportedProjects, ILogger log, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            at NuGet.Build.Tasks.RestoreTask.ExecuteAsync(ILogger log)
       Done executing task "RestoreTask" -- FAILED.
     1>Done building target "Restore" in project "restore.csproj" -- FAILED.
     1>Done Building Project "C:\Users\DevOps-AzAgent$\AppData\Local\Temp\qn20vf2i.kp0\restore.csproj" (Restore target(s)) -- FAILED.
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE 1:**

Using the task `NuGet` to restore packages works and does not need task `NuGet authenticate` to execute prior. Still, the problem is, I have to use the command `dotnet.exe tool restore` to restore some dotnet tools. It seems, that `dotnet.exe` needs some further help to authenticate properly against our nuget server hosted by Azure DevOps Server.

**UPDATE 2:**

nuget.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageRestore>
    <!-- Allow NuGet to download missing packages -->
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />

    <!-- Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio -->
    <add key="automatic" value="False" />
  </packageRestore>

  <solution>
    <!-- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#solution-section -->
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
  
  <packageSources>
    <add key="XXXFeed" value="http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

**UPDATE 3:**

For debugging purposes, I added another task into my pipeline, which runs the Azure Credential Provider in standalone mode:

`"C:\Users\DevOps-AzAgent$\.nuget\plugins\netfx\CredentialProvider.Microsoft\CredentialProvider.Microsoft.exe" -I -V Verbose -U "http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json"`

Result:

```
[Verbose] [CredentialProvider]Running in stand-alone mode
[Verbose] [CredentialProvider]Command-line v1.0.0+94af8126cf520805dd7e213b92cdecd9d8728d1f: "C:\Users\DevOps-AzAgent$\.nuget\plugins\netfx\CredentialProvider.Microsoft\CredentialProvider.Microsoft.exe"  -I -V Verbose -U "http://tfs.rzlsoftware.at:8080/tfs/RZL/_packaging/RZLFeed/nuget/v3/index.json"
[Verbose] [CredentialProvider]Handling auth request, Uri: http://tfs.rzlsoftware.at:8080/tfs/RZL/_packaging/RZLFeed/nuget/v3/index.json, IsRetry: True, IsNonInteractive: False, CanShowDialog: False
[Verbose] [CredentialProvider]URI: http://tfs.rzlsoftware.at:8080/tfs/RZL/_packaging/RZLFeed/nuget/v3/index.json
[Verbose] [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskServiceEndpointCredentialProvider - This credential provider must be run under the Team Build tasks for NuGet with external endpoint credentials. Appropriate environment variable needs to be set.
[Verbose] [CredentialProvider]Skipping NuGetCredentialProvider.CredentialProviders.VstsBuildTaskServiceEndpoint.VstsBuildTaskServiceEndpointCredentialProvider, cannot provide credentials for http://tfs.rzlsoftware.at:8080/tfs/RZL/_packaging/RZLFeed/nuget/v3/index.json
[Verbose] [CredentialProvider]Using NuGetCredentialProvider.CredentialProviders.VstsBuildTask.VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider to try to get credentials for http://tfs.rzlsoftware.at:8080/tfs/RZL/_packaging/RZLFeed/nuget/v3/index.json.
[Verbose] [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - IsRetry: True
[Verbose] [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - URI Prefixes:
[Verbose] [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - http://tfs.rzlsoftware.at:8080/tfs/RZL/
[Verbose] [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - Matched prefix: http://tfs.rzlsoftware.at:8080/tfs/RZL/
[Verbose] [CredentialProvider]VstsBuildTaskCredentialProvider - Found credentials for endpoint http://tfs.rzlsoftware.at:8080/tfs/RZL/_packaging/RZLFeed/nuget/v3/index.json
[Information] [CredentialProvider]Username: VssSessionToken
[Information] [CredentialProvider]Password: ***
```

**That seems to work?**

Answer (score 1):

Since you have granted your Build Service with Contributor permissions to the feed, then there should be sufficient permissions for the Build service to retore it. And it is not needed to add "NuGet authenticate" task.

I have tested and got work when restoring with my DefaultCollection Build service "Contributor" role, and not adding the  "NuGet authenticate" task.

(1).Test with "Contributor" role granted.

[image]

(2).Restore successfully.

[image]

And **the prerequisite** is that you should check and confirm whether the specified nuget feed is correct located in your Artifact.

**For your updates:**

If you mean you want to get the resource from the "nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" ?

You can manually add a "packages.config" file in your Repo and then edit the "packages.config" file with the specified resource URL like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<packages>

<package id="wso" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />

<!-- The packages NLog and jQuery are from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -->

<package id="NLog" version="4.3.10" targetFramework="net46" />

<package id="jQuery" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net46" />

</packages>
```

Then just run the restore task with Path specified:

[image]

Comment: You are right. When using the task `NuGet` to restore packages, it a) works and b) task `NuGet authenticate` is not required. **But**, I have to use the command `dotnet.exe tool restore` to restore some dotnet tools. It seems, that `dotnet.exe` needs some help to authenticate properly.

Comment: @roli09 Does your dotnet.exe tool is contained in the nuget.config file? And what is your dotnet.exe tool?

Comment: The feed hosting my dotnet tool is in my `nuget.config`. I added my `nuget.config` to my original post as **Update 2**.

Comment: @roli09 Hi, I have updated and edited my answer, you could check and test to see if it works.

Comment: No, as you can see in my logs, the feed I have problems with is `http://tfs.XXXsoftware.at:8080/tfs/XXX/_packaging/XXXFeed/nuget/v3/index.json`. I don't think any `packages.config` would help, because the logs suggest, that everything is picked up correctly. As mentioned earlier, if I use the *Azure Artifacts Credential Provider* in standalone-mode, looking at the logs, it seems to work.

Comment: I also already downloaded the source code of the *Azure Artifacts Credential Provider* and tried to create a version with some more output to narrow my issue down. Unfortunately, *dotnet* refuses to use my modified version of the credential provider, because it has no embedded signature.